# shell_exec not working

Tags: php, shell

Here's my command:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/jpegoptim --max=50 /home/someuser/public_html/reports/images/r121662.jpg
```

This command is supposed to compress an image. I tried running this command using backtick operator and shell_exec, neither will work. The file doesn't compress.

But this command runs when I run it directly in the shell logged in as `someuser`. I've modified `sudoers` to accept the command without requiring a password. The file is compressed when I run it in the shell.

Apache is configured to run with suPHP, and the PHP files belong to `someuser` as well. I've further ensured this by writing a test php script just saying `system(id);` and running it in the browser. That tells me that the script is indeed being run by `someuser`.

Also, safe_mode is off.

**EDIT**: Ok, I got it to output the error

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Now, what does it mean?!

Comment: Does it output something when you run it in shell?

Comment: No, i tried echoing the output, no output at all

Comment: can you sudo any other command and that works?

Comment: added /bin/ls to sudoers and did a `sudo ls` using shell_exec, no output

Comment: try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php to retreive output instead of shell_exec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Catalin , I was able to get an output. It said `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` which required requiretty to be disabled for `someuser`. That is the best solution I got, if there's a way to disable requiretty for a single user calling a single command, please let me know.

Comment: Glad i could help with the debugging :P

Comment: You can turn on requiretty for a single user with this entry on sudoers: Defaults:someuser !requiretty

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` typically requires terminal input (i.e., `must have a tty`) as it will attempt to ask the user for a password before allowing you to execute a command. Do you really need to use `sudo` to run the command?  Try removing the `sudo`.

Comment: Can you provide the specific error message?  What are the permissions on `/home/someuser/public_html/reports/images/r121662.jpg` and `/home/someuser/public_html/reports/images/`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo -S` to see if setting it to read the password from stdin (even though it doesn't need one) will bypass the test for a tty.